# What is the main difference between include_once and require_one and include and require in php?

Tags: php

When I was writing my code in **PHP** and typed `require` instead `include`, I saw there was no difference between them so I want to know the main difference between `include_once` and `require_one` and `include` and `require`.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)?

Answer (score 0):

`require()` and `require_once()` perform the same task except that the second function checks if the PHP script is already included or not before executing it.

**(same for `include_once()` and `include()`)**